# How do I rerun a static integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, static

here's the array I want to rerun:

```
public static int[] rollDice(int dice[]) {
    // generate 5 random numbers / update dice array
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    return dice;
}
```

If I want to reset this array and find new random numbers how would I do that? I tried `rollDice()` only to get an error.

Comment: What error did you get? Also, that's a method, not an array. You don't run arrays

Comment: What do you think `int dice[]` at `rollDice(int dice[])` represents?

Comment: Side note: please use `int[] dice` instead of `int dice[]`. The latter was for C programmers and is not the convention in Java

Comment: The error you got probably isn't related to the definition of method; it would help if you updated your question to list the precise (copy/paste it) error.

Comment: int dice[] is is a blank array with 5 zeros

Comment: What is its purpose in `rollDice(int dice[]){...}`? What is the difference between that and `rollDice(){..}`?

Comment: @Voxle Could you please say what error you're getting? This code should work just fine

Comment: The error message is critical here but not present, unfortunately... Though there might be no point in returning the array, this method looks valid. Please provide the error message and a small example of how you are calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in returning the array, since you already have a reference to the array when you call the method rollDice().

Arrays are sent by reference and not by value, which means you are **not** working with a copy like you do with ints, instead you are modifing the original array.

Change the return type to void and remove the return and your code should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can get every time a new dynamic length array with random numbers, and you can access by call rollDice(integer value). 

public static int[] rollDice(int length) {
         final int dice[] = new int [length];
        // generate array with random values
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dice[i] = (int)(Math.random() * length + 1);
        }

        return dice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a class member like this:

```java
public static final int[] dice = new int[5];
```

Then to roll/reroll the dice use your method, else just access `dice`.

```java
public static void rollDice() {
    // generate 5 random numbers / update dice array
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }
}
```

---

Interesting fact: Java has no static function variables as C and C++ does. In those languages it could look like this:
(I wrote it like a java Function for you Java guys)

```
public static int[5] rollDice(boolean reroll) {
    static final int[] dice = new int[5];
    if (reroll) for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }
    return dice;
}
```

As you can see, static variables can be embedded into those functions. If you ask me, it's a huge minus, Java doesn't support this as I use it all the time to hide those from the class namespace.

Comment: The method signature in the question is different. It was hidden earlier, so you might not have seen it. `dice` is actually a parameter to the method `rollDice`

Comment: @user It looks like OP code was just attempt to solve his problem, not some *mandatory* approach.